# PHP/MongoDB JSON Encode - Can't access private variables of an inner class when calling json_encode()

Tags: php, mongodb, json, private-members

So basically, I am trying to encode a php class object I have, and insert it directly into MongoDB. Problem is, my class has an array variable meant to hold previous versions of the class, so those private variables can't be accessed by JSON encode. How can I get around this? An example of how my class is set up is below (it's much bigger, but this should help you get the idea)

```
class App {
    private $version_number = "1.0.1";
    private $previous_versions= array(); //each element in the array will be a previous version of the App object 

    public function storeOldVersions(){
        $clone = clone $this;
        array_unshift($this->previous_versions, $clone);
    }
}
```

So I do something like:

```
$app = new App();
$app->storeOldVersions();
echo json_encode($app);
```

And the echo of the json_encode correct shows the $app object's data, but the $previous_version array's json encoding is blank because its variables are private. How can I fix this, without making each app object's variables public?

Thanks!

Comment: Just a minor issue: `class App() {` should be `class App {`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a public getter to return the previous_versions array:

```
public function getPreviousVersions()
{
    return $this->previous_versions;
}
```

-- Edit --

I read up on the php docs for json_encode, it looks like someone came across the same issue you have. Check out https://www.php.net/json_encode, and search for the code submission by "mic dot sumner at gmail dot com" on 02-Jul-2010 01:39, it looks like he came up with a custom solution to make private members available after a json_encode call.

Comment: I already have that - but I'm trying to use the json_encode function

Comment: @ZakRyterman: This seems to be by design. If a member variable has private/protected scope, why would json_encode break that scope? Have you considered serialize(), it appears to work.

Comment: hmm, i'll check out serialize

Comment: @ZakRyterman: Updated post, see if that code excerpt will help.

Comment: @DigitalPrecison: thanks I'll check it out. I want to preserve json format cause that works nicely with Mongo

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow `json_encode` to access *private* or *protected* members you need to expose them first. You can do this inside some sort of helper function. Usage:

```
$app = new App();

echo json_encode_private($app), "\n";
```

Which could then output like so:

```
{"_App_version_number":"1.0.1","_App_previous_versions":{}}
```

This version of such a function is pretty bare, it makes use of a simple feature in PHP to make private and protected members visible:

```
/**
 * json_encode object including private and protected members
 * 
 * @param object $object
 * @return string JSON
 */
function json_encode_private($object)
{
    if (!is_object($object))
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Object type mismatch.');

    $json = json_encode((array) $object, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
    $json = preg_replace('~([{,]")\\\\u0000(\w+)\\\\u0000~i', '$1_$2_', $json);
    $json = preg_replace('~([{,]")\\\\u0000(\*)\\\\u0000~i', '$1_', $json);

    return $json;
}
```

It's making use of a regular expression, I just have another idea but I need to test it first. Hope this is helpful.

**Edit:** How does it work?

The cast to array `(array)` will make the private properties available to `json_encode`. As it's now an array, `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` will make the json again to encode it as an object.

The regular expressions are used to re-name the private and protected properties as they contain special NUL byte markers which aren't handy if you want to load the object in javascript.

As it's only a regular expression and not a json parser, similar formatted data inside properties will get changed, too, but I assume this is most often not the case. But be warned.

Additionally take notice that this doesn't work for complex objects recursively with this version.

It should be possible to extend this based on [PHP's *Reflection<sup>­Docs</sup>*](http://php.net/Reflection) capabilities. This would also allow to filter specific members or access types as well as to define a more detailed scheme how these members should be named.

Comment: this looks like it's my answer, even though I have no idea what's going on haha

Comment: tried it, still having problems. my previous_versions array looks like " "_App_previous_versions":{"0":{}},